# ironpython 2.7 visual studio 2013 ptvs 2.2 intellisense not working

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, ironpython, ptvs

I think the title is fairly descriptive of the problem I'm having.

After some searching online I found that the IntelliSense databases can be refreshed by going to

View->Other Windows->Python Environments

In this way I was able to refresh the databases on IronPython 2.7 and IronPython 64-bit 2.7 (currently the default environment for new projects)

My projects run fine but I'm missing the benefit of syntax highlights and autocompletes etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to update to [PTVS 2.2.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/tag/v2.2.2), which had some IronPython-related fixes compared to 2.2.

Otherwise, for issues that look like bugs (rather than a mistake on your part), reporting it to the development team at https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS is a much more efficient way to get a response. (In this case, we'd ask for more details about what does work vs. what doesn't work - StackOverflow isn't a great forum for that.)